# How do I enter combat in Mass Effect?

Tags: mass-effect

I am playing Mass Effect as an Infiltrator with the Sole Survivor background.

It seems every time I try to enter combat I get killed, instantly. I managed to make it past the railway station (where you disarm the bombs) and to get to Fist, but in both cases it was bordering on frustrating rather than fun.

At the moment I have resorted to sending my squad in while I hide or snipe as they can respawn when killed.

How can I enter the fray myself without being killed almost instantly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are an infiltrator, you aren't supposed to be able to tank enemies.  I don't know exactly what skills you've allocated, but here are some things that may help you out:

1. Put some points into electronics, each point gives you a boost to shield strength.
2. You can try assigning more points into tactical armor until you can wear medium armor.
3. Your weapons are pistols and sniper rifles.  Stay in hiding, and pop out to shoot a single shot against an enemy (try to go for a headshot), before going back into hiding.
4. If you have enough points into electronics, you'll unlock damping which can stun enemies for a short duration.  Also, try starting out fights by using overload to quickly take out enemy shields.
5. If your shields are down, stay under cover until it recharges, or you will die very fast.
6. Try to use tankish followers, such as Ashley.

Now, against the Fist fight, he will never wander out of his room, so you can just use the side of the doors for cover and pop out, shoot 1 turret, and then retreat until your shields come back up.

Comment: Agreed, the Infiltrator is best at ducking in and out of cover to shoot, and hiding like a pansy when shields go down. If you want more of a run-and-gun experience, you could reroll as a soldier. When I played as Infiltrator, my squadmates were usually Wrex and Ashley, as they could run up and draw enemies' attention for me.

Answer (score 1):

LOL this is funny. Exactly in this moment I'm playing Mass Effect 1, Infiltrator, Survivor.

At the beginning, the game is a bit harder because you got low skills. Use pistols + marksman and assasination + sniper. As yx said, you should go for medium armor.

yx is spot on. What I can tell you however is this: don't worry, the game will become more fun as soon as you reach about level 10. The Infiltrator rocks. You become extremely powerful later, I believe this is a late-game character, but I may be wrong (maybe all characters get very strong late-game, but I think that in the case of the the Infiltrator, this is more pronounced).

Don't despair, keep at it. Mass Effect rocks ::- D.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what class you have, you eventually get quite powerful if you get the right armor and equip the right mods (Frictionless Materials X means almost unlimited shooting!).

Comment: I never found Frictionless Materials X

Comment: You will eventually.